# How to replace multiple column values for specific row in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe with thousand columns, I want to replace a few columns (which I stored in a dictionary) for a specific row, how can I do that?

```
    my_dict={'a':2,'b':1} #total feature is more than this.
    Df.loc[i]=my_dict #i is row index
```

If you have another method to do without considering the dictionary then please suggest me, I will twerk my code accordingly. I just want to complete this operation.

Comment: I'm confused by what you want to accomplish. Lets say you have columns "a" through "z". Given `{'a': 2, 'b': 1}` you are trying to replace df.loc[i, 'a'] with 2 and df.loc[i, 'b'] with 1 without touching columns "c" through "z" on that same row?

Comment: If you are trying to do that, do you have a whole bunch of dictionaries with different column names (that is to say, essentially random edits all over the table)? Do you have something where you need to replace all values in a column that meet some criteria? Basically what I'm getting at is: is there some way to logically group the edits you need to make? Because pandas has some functions that can act on like columns and stuff and it'd be easier and faster than random edits.

Comment: Yes I want to edit columns 'a' and 'b' without touching 'c'(I don't understand what 'z' is). No I cannot logically group those columns. @FailureGod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have this input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4], 'c':[5,6]})
d = {'a':2,'b':1}
i = 0
```

Then you can do:

```
df.loc[i,d.keys()] = d.values()
```

`df` output:

```
    a   b   c
0   2   1   5
1   2   4   6
```